# How to generate 400MHz & 500MHz clocks from 100MHz clock using Verilog?

Tags: verilog, clock

For 400 MHz:

```
realtime delay =1.25;
always begin
#delay clk=0;
#delay clk=1;
```

This isn't working.

Comment: in general you can not. You can generate slower clocks from faster, but no vice versa. it is better to have a fast clock which is a common denominator of all slower clocks. So, you can easily generate both from a 2Ghz clock but not from 100Mhz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to generate the 3 clocks, where the 100MHz clock is synchronous to the other two:

```
`timescale 1ns/10ps

module tb;

reg clk1, clk2, clk3;

initial begin : clk_100MHz
    clk1 = 0;
    forever #5 clk1 <= ~clk1;
end

initial begin : clk_500MHz
    clk2 = 0;
    forever #1 clk2 <= ~clk2;
end

initial begin : clk_400MHz
    clk3 = 0;
    forever #1.25 clk3 <= ~clk3;
end

endmodule
```

---

You didn't show your complete code.  Two reasons I can think of why your code did not work:

1. You declared `clk` as 4-state signal, like `reg`, but did not initialize it to 0 or 1, and it remained `x` in your simulation.
2. You did not set your timescale appropriately to generate the desired frequency.